# If $\gcd(h,k)=1$ and the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $h$ and the order of $b$ modulo $n$ is $k$ then show that $ab$ has order $hk$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(h,k)=1$ and the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $h$ and the order of
$b$ modulo $n$ is $k$ then show that $ab$ has order $hk$

---

So far I figured out 
$(ab)^{hk} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

But this doesn't prove  order of $ab$ is $hk$. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, I think.

All you have to do now is to show that $ ab $ can't have order $ h $ or order $ k $, then you're finished, since $ \gcd(h,k) = 1 $.

And of course order $ 1 $ shouldn't be possible, too.